# Changing DataType of a Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `DateTime(null)` column as `StartDate` in one of my tables schema.
Clients already have entered lots of data in their table based on that.
Now they want that column to be of type `Character(10)` 
Is it possible to do that? Won't it damage the data they already have entered? What is a safe way to do this?

Comment: What is `Character(10)`?

Comment: you can play by inserting into other table. I mean one temp table and then by doing cast we can achieve this.

Comment: Create a new column, fill it with the data you need (based on the original column data using e.g. `UPDATE` statement), delete old column, rename the new column. Might get you in trouble because of different column ordering if anyone queries it using `*` though.

Comment: Why go to char(10) for datetime values?!?

Comment: Why do the clients want to change the datatype? If they want to enter data that represents the start date then the `DateTime` should be suitable; if they want to enter data that does not represent the start date then a new, appropriately-named column should be set up.

Comment: @jarlh Becuase they are lazy and don't want to enter "day" in the application, they just care about month and year.  And app doesn't let them to only type two parts of a date so now they say make it a string so we can just type month and year.

Comment: Just say no. Since when is the client responsible for database design? if the values are datetime, or date, storing them in char can only do harm. you might want to change the database from datetime to date, but do not agree to change it to char under any circumstances.

Comment: @Bohn . . . Then default the day to 01 and only show it to them using the year and month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT StartDate, CONVERT(CHAR, StartDate, 10) AS NEWOUTPUT
FROM yourtable
```

If the results of the NEWOUTPUT column are fine then go ahead with..

```
alter table yourtable alter column StartDate char(10) not null;
```

Comment: Now how do I do the actual conversion? Thanks.

Comment: @SQLPolice , thanks! i appreciate these however anymore and they will get revesed by the up vote script i would imagine as its too many upvotes from the same user to the same user per day

Answer (score 1):

A direct change could lead to troubles. You would need to

1. Create a new column
2. Update your table so that the new column is filled with `YEAR(datecolname) + '-' + MONTH(datecolname) + '-' + DAY(datecolname)`.
3. Delete the old column
4. Rename the new column to the old name
5. Recreate indexes

One thing though is that the searches for specific dates WILL probably be slower in any case if you use char instead of datetime and specific sql statements like "between" won't work any longer.

If it is just as you mentioned in a comment because they dont want to type in a day, then it would probably be better to change how they have to type in the dates so that the day is defaultwise set to 1. But depends on the application in question.